# Converting an integer to binary

Tags: plc, structured-text

I am using Connected Components Workbench V12 with a Micro850 PLC

I am trying to take an input from a barcode scanner and convert the scanned integer input to a 8-bit binary number to use each bit as a boolean to trigger outputs on the PLC.

I am expecting the FOR loop to get the remainder for the input/2 and repeat for the remaining bits.
for example I input 21 and expect a 0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1 but only get a 1 on the 8th bit

[Here's a Screenshot of the Variable Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsKAr.png)

```
out_Complete := in_Enable;
IF in_Enable THEN
    B[8]:= ANY_TO_DINT(in_Integer_Input);   //convert input to DINT
    Ba[8]:= ANY_TO_DINT(in_Integer_Input);
    
    FOR X := 1 TO 8 BY 1 DO
        B[X]:= MOD(Ba[X],2);                //get remainder for [x] bit
        Ba[X]:= B[X] / 2;                   //divide by 2
        OutputBit[X]:= ANY_TO_BOOL(B[X]);   //set output bit 
    END_FOR;
END_IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

`Ba[X]` is always zero, except for index 8, because that is the one you set.

Another way to check the bits would be try [bit access](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.12.0/en/_cds_operands_variables_accessing_bits/). Or [bit shifting](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.12.0/en/_cds_operands_variables_accessing_bits/) combined with AND, something like this

```
FOR X := 0 TO 7 BY 1 DO
   B[X]:= SHR(in_Integer_Input, X) AND 1;
END_FOR;
```